# Cannot keep a device connected via Bluetooth

Tags: pi-2, bluetooth

I am working on a raspberry pi bot project, and I am having some issues with 
keeping bluetooth devices connected for longer than a period of 10 seconds.

I can pair the devices through blueman and through the hcitool. However, if and when I connect to the devices they do not stay connected longer than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

use your text editor to create a new file like:

```
echo "options bt_driver_name_here power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/bt_driver_name.conf
```

example:

```
echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf
```